# Почему не подключается javascript файл?

Tags: html

Так работает:

```
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
```

Так не работает:

```
<script src="../lib/dropzone.js"></script>
```

```
.
├── css/
│   ├── dropzone.css
│   └── main.css
├── index.html
├── lib/
│   └── dropzone.js
└── pages/
    └──dropzonetest.html
```

Скрипт вставляется в `dropzonetest.html`.
Почему и как исправить?

Comment: Это у вас всё просто статика, или чем-то собирается? Пробовали просто `<script src="/lib/dropzone.js"></script>`?

Comment: Потому что путь неправильный - вы зачем-то ищете lib на каталог выше чем надо

Comment: Ничем не собирается. Кидаю на сервер и все. Попробовал. Не раработает. И почему-то по ссылке открывается js файл с  html содержимым, а не js файл. Хотя на сервере лежит точно js файл с кодом dropzone(проверил). Может кэширование, потому-что этот файл там был с именем dropzone.js с html содержимым (не то скачал сперва)

Comment: @Klimenkomud, добавьте ответ про <script src="/lib/dropzone.js"></script> и я отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключайте свой скрипт следующим образом: `<script src="/lib/dropzone.js"></script>`